# why am i getting expected identifier error code?

Tags: c

I'm working on an assignment on C language and I think I messed up somewhere but I can not find it at all which is very frustrating.

this is the error

```
" }
 ^
main.c:160:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
 {  
 ^
"
```

I've tried searching for misclicks and such but I can't find it.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int PASSENGER_SIZE=7;
const int FLIGHT_SIZE=6;
void O_F1_6(int arr[], int N);
float O_F2_6(int arr[]);
void O_F4_6(int arr[][FLIGHT_SIZE], int IdPass[],char frqflyr[]);
int O_F3_6(int arr[], int IdFlight[], int numtrips);
int main()
{
   int IDs_passengers [PASSENGER_SIZE];
   int IDs_flights [FLIGHT_SIZE];
   int Flight_frequency[PASSENGER_SIZE][FLIGHT_SIZE];
   char Freq_flyers [PASSENGER_SIZE];
   int i, j,p, f,pos, flid;
   float avg;
   printf("Enter the Ids of %d passengers: \n",PASSENGER_SIZE);
   for (i=0; i < PASSENGER_SIZE; +i) {
       scanf("%d", IDs_passengers + i);
       if(*(IDs_passengers + i)==-11)
       break;
       
   }
   for(j=i;j<PASSENGER_SIZE; ++i)
     * (IDs_passengers + j)=-10;
     
     printf("Enter the Ids of %d flights: \n", FLIGHT_SIZE);
     for (i = 0; i < FLIGHT_SIZE; ++i){
         scanf("%d", IDs_flights + i);
         if(*(IDs_flights + i)==-11)
         break;
         
     }
     for(j=i;j<FLIGHT_SIZE; ++i)
     *(IDs_flights + j)==-10;
 printf("Enter the number of trips for each passenger: \n");
 for (i =0; i < PASSENGER_SIZE; ++i){
     if(*(IDs_passengers + i)==-10)
       break;
    else
    {
        printf("Passenger with ID=%d : ",*(IDs_passengers + i));
        O_F1_6(*(Flight_frequency+i),i);
        
    }
}
printf("\n********************************************************\n");
printf("Passenger Id\t Average trips\n");
  for (i = 0 ; i < PASSENGER_SIZE; i++)
  {
      avg=O_F2_6(*(Flight_frequency+i));
      printf("%d \t %f\n",*(IDs_passengers + i), avg);
}
printf("\n********************************************************\n");
O_F4_6(Flight_frequency, IDs_passengers, Freq_flyers);
printf("\n********************************************************\n");
printf("Enter the Passenger id and frequency of trip for a flight");
scanf("%d%d",&p,&f);
pos=-1;
for (i =0; i < PASSENGER_SIZE; i++)
 {
    if((*(IDs_passengers + i))==p)
 {
     pos=i;
     break;
     
 }
     
 }
 if(pos!=-1)
 {
     flid=O_F3_6(*(Flight_frequency+pos), IDs_flights, f);
     if(flid!=-1) {
         printf("The flight id is %d",flid);             }
     else         { 
         printf("Required information not found");       }
     
 }
 else           {
     printf("Required information not found");         }
 printf("\n********************************************************\n");
 return 0;
}
void O_F1_6(int arr[], int N)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < FLIGHT_SIZE; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", arr + i);
        if(*(arr + i)==-11)
        break;
        
    }
    for(j=i;j<FLIGHT_SIZE; ++j)
    *(arr + j)=-10;
}
float O_F2_6(int arr[])
{
    int i,sum,c;
    float avg;
    sum=c=0;
    for(i = 0; i < FLIGHT_SIZE; ++i){
        if(*(arr+i) !=-1){
        sum=sum+(*(arr + i));
        c++;
        }
        
    }
    avg=sum/c;
    return avg;
}
void O_F4_6(int Flight_frequency[ ][FLIGHT_SIZE], int Id_Pass[],char frqflyr[])
{
    int i, j, sum;
    printf("Passenger Id\t Frequent Flyer\n");
    for (i= 0; i < PASSENGER_SIZE; i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(j = 0; j < FLIGHT_SIZE; ++i) {
            if( *( *(Flight_frequency + i) + j)!=-10){
                sum=sum+(*(*(Flight_frequency + i) +j));
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    if(sum<250)
    {
        frqflyr[i]='R';
        printf("%d\t Regular\n",*(Id_Pass + i));
        
    }
    else if((sum=250)&&(sum<=1150))
    {
        frqflyr[i]='S';
        printf("%d It Silver\n",*(Id_Pass + i)) ;
        
    }
    else if((sum>1150)&&(sum<2150))
    {
        frqflyr[i]='P';
        printf("%d It Platinum \n",*(Id_Pass + i));
        
    }
    else
    {}
}
}
int O_F3_6(int arr[], int IdFlight[], int numtrips)
  {
    int i;
    int rt=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<FLIGHT_SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(*(arr + i)==numtrips)
        {
            rt=IdFlight[i];
            return rt;
        }
    }
  }
{  
return rt;
}
```

Comment: `else if((sum=250)&&(sum<=1150))` is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra close brace at the end of `O_F4_6` (line 146), and also mismatched braces at the end of `O_F3_6` before `return rt;`, where the braces on lines 159 and 160 should not be there.

See https://godbolt.org/z/KGG89qGnW for a fixed version.  I commented out the offending lines (marked REMOVED) instead of deleting them so that the line numbers don't change.

(Also note there are several compiler warnings shown there, that suggest additional mistakes in your code.  Please study them carefully.)

If you use an editor or tool to automatically indent your code, mistakes like this will become visually obvious.

Comment: I've just tried removing them and it still gives me this error "main.c:161:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘return’
 return rt;
 ^~~~~~"

Comment: @Meshari: It works for me, I suspect you fixed it incorrectly.  See my edited post.

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response and easy fix !! I'll make sure to check the errors :)